# replace text in update.ver with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I wrote this script to replace lines in a file, but its taking a very long time. Is there a way to speed it up?

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set INTEXTFILE=update.ver
set OUTTEXTFILE=update.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=93.184.71.27
set REPLACETEXT=93.184.72.27
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

    >> %OUTTEXTFILE% echo(!modified!
    endlocal
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%





@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set INTEXTFILE=update.ver
set OUTTEXTFILE=update.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=91.228.167.26
set REPLACETEXT=91.227.167.26
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

    >> %OUTTEXTFILE% echo(!modified!
    endlocal
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%





@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set INTEXTFILE=update.ver
set OUTTEXTFILE=update.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=91.228.166.13
set REPLACETEXT=91.227.166.13
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

    >> %OUTTEXTFILE% echo(!modified!
    endlocal
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%





@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set INTEXTFILE=update.ver
set OUTTEXTFILE=update.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=91.228.166.15
set REPLACETEXT=91.227.166.15
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

    >> %OUTTEXTFILE% echo(!modified!
    endlocal
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

please help me

Comment: You forgot to tell us, what the problem is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL

set "INTEXTFILE=update.ver"
set "OUTTEXTFILE=update.txt"
set "SEARCHTEXT1=93.184.71.27"
set "REPLACETEXT1=93.184.72.27"
set "SEARCHTEXT2=91.228.167.26"
set "REPLACETEXT2=91.227.167.26"
set "SEARCHTEXT3=91.228.166.13"
set "REPLACETEXT3=91.227.166.13"
set "SEARCHTEXT4=91.228.166.15"
set "REPLACETEXT4=91.227.166.15"

(for /f "delims=" %%A in ( 'type "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET "string=%%A"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT1%=%REPLACETEXT1%!"
    SET "modified=!modified:%SEARCHTEXT2%=%REPLACETEXT2%!"
    SET "modified=!modified:%SEARCHTEXT3%=%REPLACETEXT3%!"
    SET "modified=!modified:%SEARCHTEXT4%=%REPLACETEXT4%!"
    echo(!modified!
    endlocal
))>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"

move "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use my FindRepl.bat program to achieve multiple string replacements in just one processing pass of the file. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set INTEXTFILE=update.ver
set OUTTEXTFILE=update.txt
set "SEARCHTEXT=93\.184\.71\.27|91\.228\.167\.26|91\.228\.166\.13|91\.228\.166\.15"
set "REPLACETEXT=93\.184\.72\.27|91\.227\.167\.26|91\.227\.166\.13|91\.227\.166\.15"
call FindRepl "%SEARCHTEXT%" /A "%REPLACETEXT%" < %INTEXTFILE% > %OUTTEXTFILE%
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

The /A switch in FindRepl indicate that both Search and Replace strings have several values separated by vertical bars.

FindRepl.bat is a Batch-JScript hybrid program, so it run much faster than any pure Batch solution; you don't need anything additional in order to use it, just download it from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697)

Comment: @MortezaKhodadadi: Ops, my mistake! I forgot to insert a backslash before every point! This is needed in regular expressions... Please, copy again the Batch program above